# Multiple Ubuntu download locations

Tags: downloads

I am looking at the below download locations for Ubuntu. Can someone educate me on the reasons for having these many of them?

```
http://releases.ubuntu.com/20.10
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/daily-live/current/
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/20.10/release/
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/daily-live/current/
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/20.10/release/
```

Answer (score 0):

All of these are valid links, hosting different versions (some of which are old, some are development versions) and editions (server and desktop) of Ubuntu. Also, Ubuntu stores its installation images in multiple servers across the world, and you may find more links hosted by many companies and academic institutions.

To get the latest stable supported version of Ubuntu, head on to [Ubuntu website](http://ubuntu.com) and download.

https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop